# strftime issue with different formats

Tags: c++, date, time, strftime, time-t

```
string Account::dateCreated(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

        strftime (buffer,80,"%a %b %d %T %Z %Y",timeinfo);
        return buffer;
}
```

For some reason this does not return anything but when I change this slightly it works:

```
string Account::dateCreated(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (buffer,80,"%A %d/%m/%Y",timeinfo);
    return buffer;
}
```

The output before was: nothing

The output now is: Saturday 13/01/2018

Comment: [How to return local array in C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7769998)

Comment: What compiler are you working with?

Comment: MinGW compiler and eclipse ide

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I thought that at first too, but it looks like its being converted to a string.

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, it's unclear as OP has `string` and `String` return types.

Comment: it is a string.

Comment: here is my reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: @NeilShah So this is working for me on gcc6.3 Can you ell me what version of gcc you're using?

Comment: Seems to work ok (with std::string) on ideone: https://ideone.com/3UkJZc

Comment: how do I figure that out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296299/2642059

Comment: I have no idea but I got MinGW in December 2017

Comment: Find your gcc executable and run: gcc --version

Comment: I have gcc 6.3.0

Comment: If `localtime` is being called by more than one thread in your program, the value of `*timeinfo` can be compromised between the call to `localtime` and the call to `strftime`.

Comment: then what should I do

Comment: It depends on your needs.  Personally I decided to never use the C API again, [write my own API](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), and then [try to get it standardized](https://wg21.link/p0355).

Comment: I figured it out. for some reason "%T" is not working on my computer.

Comment: @NeilShah Good research sir. It would probably be helpful to answer your own question here and accept it in case anyone else working with MGWin stumbles into the same issue.